# Serial communication issue

Tags: python, c++, arduino, serial-port, usb

I'm making a project which works with an Arduino via USB. I'm using nearly the same code which was in the library I am using.

The code reads a .txt file, and sends this data to the Arduino in an infinite loop. The problem is that after the 165th loop, it really slows down. It takes the connection 6 seconds to send 6 characters. Always at 165.
Here is the code:

```
while(SP->IsConnected()) {
  //see if the usb connection is on.
  fstream file;
  file.open("c:/Python27/beki.txt");
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    file >> incomingData[i];
    cout << incomingData[i];
  }
  file.close();
  cout <<szam << "\n";
  SP->WriteData(incomingData,dataLength);
  szam++; //counting, thats why i know its always slows at 166.
  Sleep(200);
}
```

I figured out that it's not the file, and it does not eat much memory, 335k. And it sends good data, so until the 165th loop, it does its work perfectly. The file is written by another infinite loop, and after this 165th loop, the code sends old data's characters.

It did the same in Python. I don't know if there's a limit or something. Please help.

I'm using [this library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows).

Comment: Did you try to run the loop without calling `SP->WriteData()`? Or without opening, reading and closing the file every time? Try to eliminate as much of the code until you are left with what is causing the problem.

Comment: why is this tagged python?

Comment: writefile is writing the data to arduino, i can not eliminate that.
i tried this without filereading but an in code array, it did the same. its something with the serial.
its tagged because i tried this code in python, and it did this loop failure there too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the following outside of your while loop:

```
fstream file;
file.open("c:/Python27/beki.txt");
```

and

```
file.close();
```

As it is now, you are probably sending the same bytes after opening the file each time.

Comment: the file is always written by another code, if i do what you explained, this code would send the same data, because without open and close inside loop, it reads the file only once. am i wrong?

Comment: @cracken - when you open a file, the filepointer points to the beginning of the file. So each time you reopen it, it points to the same data unless the file is changed each time you loop.. Is that other code called from an interrupt? Maybe you should post some more code to make it clear what you are doing.

Comment: @cracken - ok, seems this code is not running on Arduino, but sending to Arduino.. Is your Arduino handling the incoming data ok? Are you using multithreading on the sending system?

Comment: yes, the data handling is perfect.
multithreading? what do you mean?

Comment: i need to re open it, because the data in the file changes more times than this code runs. theres no problem with the file thing, i tried the code with a pre declared array:
incomingData="01234";
it did the same.